# Is there a way to get the exact time someone else posted a comment on Imgur?

Tags: imgur

I am trying to find out when a comment was posted on a picture on Imgur. Neither the comment or the pic is mine. Is there a way to do this?  I have tried going through the API but get an error. Perhaps I am doing something wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is hover over the approximate time with your cursor to reveal the exact time like this:

[image: 0]

---

In source code it can be found like this:

[image: 0]